# how to resize frame from video and then retrieve the final size?

Tags: python, video, image-resizing, opencv

I want to read a video file, break it into separate frames, resize each frame to a max width and then retrieve width and height of final image.

I've tried this:

while True:

```
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])
# grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
# to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
frame = vs.read()
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

# grab the frame dimensions and convert it to a blob
w, h = cv.GetSize(frame)
```

but am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "real_time_object_detection.py", line 52, in <module>
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 69, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

why does it complain about a line in `imutils/`? How can I do the required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The read method returns two variables, first is the success variables which is a boolean (True if a frame is captured else False) and the second is the frame. You're likely reading a video with 3 channel frames and the frame is usually a numpy array so you can use the shape attribute.

I would suggest using [cv2.resize](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html) for resizing.

```
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])
# grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
# to have a maximum width of 400 pixels

_, frame = vs.read()
(w, h, c) = frame.shape

#syntax: cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
img = cv2.resize(frame,(400, h))

print(w, h)
print(img.shape)
>> 480 640
 (640, 400, 3) #rows(height), columns(width), channels(BGR)
```

`w` and `h` store the original width and height of your video frame and `img.shape` has the resized width and height

Answer (score 1):

I think the frame variable you are passing is not a numpy array, it is a tuple. Hence the error. Check if the video is being read correctly. do a `print(type(frame))` and check if it is numpy to verify your image is being read correctly. imutils.resize() is a class using cv2.resize function. This is how it works

```
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])
# grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
# to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
ret, frame = vs.read()


#inside of imutils.resize()
w,h,c=frame.shape
r = 400 / float(w)
dim = (400, int(h * r))
new_frame=cv2.resize(image,dim)
```